# Angular2 reference component inside another component

Tags: angular, reference, components

I am following an Angular2 tutorial and I have to reference an extra component to the main component. 
I want to insert the template from the "CoursesComponent" inside the < courses > tag of the main component. For this I am using "directives: []", but it's not working. I get the error: 'courses' is not a known element'.
Is directives no longer used for this, and I should do it differently?

App.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My first Angular2 app</h1><courses></courses>',
  directives: [CoursesComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

Courses.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})

export class CoursesComponent {}
```

Comment: Are you using angular2 RC.6?

Comment: You have to tell us which version of Angular2 are you using right now?

Comment: It's Angular2 RC.6, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **NOTE** : *IN RC6, you don't have to declare **directives** and **pipes** meta properties within **@Component***

As **AppComponent** uses **CourseComponent**, you have to declare **CourseComponent** in declaration metadata of **@NgModule** as shown below.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,CoursesComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**NOTE**: Now, You have to remove **directives metadata** used within **@Component**.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CoursesComponent} from './courses.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My first Angular2 app</h1><courses></courses>',
  //directives: [CoursesComponent]        //<-----remove this from here
})

export class AppComponent {}
```